# CIFS mount - fstab versus manual - loss of writing privileges

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have a samba shares drive that is mounted at boot that works as I intend. Here is the fstab file:

```
//192.168.1.2/ext4tb /mnt/ext4tb cifs ,credentials=/home/frepie/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,user  0  0
```

When this works normally, I have total read,write and execute privileges on that share

Sometimes, for reasons that I ignore, that shared drive is not mounted at boot. Trying to resolve the issue without rebooting, I used the command

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.2/ext4tb /mnt/ext4tb
```

And the command requests the root password on the samba server

```
Password for root@//192.168.1.2/ext4tb:  ********
```

The problem is the when doing so, I don't have the write privileges that I have when the mount at boot works normally.

```
$ mv /home/frepie/Music/Dark\ Latin\ Groove\ -\ La\ Quiero\ A\ Morir /mnt/ext4tb/media/Audio/
mv: cannot create regular file '/mnt/ext4tb/media/Audio/Dark Latin Groove - La Quiero A Morir': Permission denied
```

Somehow, I am not granted the same privileges when the mount is performed by fstab at boot.

Comment: IIRC `mount` only consults the `fstab` file if either the device OR mountpoint is given: does it work if you simply do `sudo mount /mnt/ext4tb` for example?

Comment: Seems you put your finger on something: When I do as you suggested (sudo mount /mnt/ext4tb), it works iéeé the drive is mounted as with fstab. When I do sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.2/ext4tb /mnt/ext4tb, the drive is mounted but without writing privileges....Can you point me to a proper page that would explain this behavior?

Comment: How about a simple `sudo mount -a` ? That uses `fstab`.

Comment: I get an error when I do that:
"mount error(5): Input/output error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the behavior that you're looking for (i.e. consulting the `/etc/fstab` file, and applying the options found there) only applies if you call `mount` directly, rather than one of the "helper" commands like `mount.cifs`, and only if you specify EITHER the device or the mountpoint. From `man mount`:

> ```
>    If only the directory or the device is given, for example:
>
>           mount /dir
>
>    then  mount looks for a mountpoint (and if not found then for a device)
>    in the /etc/fstab file.  It's possible to use the --target or  --source
>    options  to avoid ambivalent interpretation of the given argument.  For
>    example:
>
>           mount --target /mountpoint
> ```

So replace

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.2/ext4tb /mnt/ext4tb
```

by either

```
sudo mount /mnt/ext4tb
```

or

```
sudo mount //192.168.1.2/ext4tb
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i do exactly the same : smb shares declared in `/etc/fstab` except that is do not automount, and i stored credential files in encrypted folders. I do not experience no issue.

Here is an extract of `/etc/fstab` on 18.04

```
//192.168.1.100/video  /media/user/Video  cifs  noauto,user,_netdev,sec=ntlm,credentials=/home/user/Crypt/credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=1.0  0 0
```

See `uid=1000,gid=1000`

You may add thoses option : explicitly specify grouid an userid of your Ubuntu user

With the `noauto` option i like, shares are mounted when I click to open them from nautilus file manager.

Using `_netdev` option means that this mount needs a network

Comment: The problem I have is not with the fstab file, it is when I try to mount it manually. Somehow, permissions are not the same as when mounted with fstab at boot.

Comment: why need you to mount manually

Comment: Because sometimes, for a reason unknown, the automount at boot is not applied.

Comment: give a try to the fstab options  i suggest (noauto, _netdev, gid, uid) and let us know if it goes better ... you may then get the manual mount with simple `mount /to/destination`

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer is to simply mount the drive without cifs i.e.

```
sudo mount /mnt/ext4tb
```