# Samba no longer mounts at boot

Tags: boot, mount, samba, fstab, automount

I have a samba shared drive that I use to keep files that are available to anyone on the network. This drive is mounted at boot on my computers. Here is the fstab file:

```
`# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
 #
 # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
 # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
 # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
 #
 # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
 # / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
 UUID=8429aa44-e70e-4fc4-8547-cafde77d1404 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
 # /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
 UUID=4E93-0D75  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
 # swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
 UUID=f002a1ef-f3e3-4cf0-a832-b0f683895bd2 none            swap    sw              0       0
 UUID=f002a1ef-f3e3-4cf0-a832-b0f683895bd2 none            swap    sw              0       0
 //192.168.1.2/ext4tb /media/ext4tb cifs users,guest,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,user 0 0`
```

This used to work fine until I had to upgrade to 18.04 LTS  for some other reason unrelated to this issue. Before reinstalling, I made sure I had a copy of fstab since it worked just fine.

But now, the shared drive no longer automounts at boot and I need to enter my credentials even if though access is open to all.

Comment: can you add the output of `sudo mount -a`

Comment: Did you also recreate the folder of `/mnt/ext4tb` on your system for the mount point?

Comment: @Terrance: Yes it has been created

Comment: Just checking.  One other question though, you also installed the `cifs-utils`?

Comment: @Terrance: Yes I did

Comment: This may very well be a stupid comment but I looked at your other question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042699/cifs-mount-fstab-versus-manual-loss-of-writing-privileges. Is the problem that it "no longer mounts at boot"? Or is the problem that it doesn't mount at all. Does it mount with a "sudo mount /mnt/ext4tb" or as Nick Sillito suggested a "sudo mount -a"?

Comment: @Morbius1: Yes it is related. It should mount automatically but sometines it doesn't. I use Clementine to play my music and my music library is on that share. Now when I start Clementine, it says that the library is empty. I have to mount the drive manually.

Comment: @Nick Sillito
     `frepie@silencio:~$ sudo mount -a
     [sudo] password for frepie: 
     frepie@silencio:~$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like fstab is being executed before your network stack is up. Here is one way to remedy that:

[1] Create a file at: /etc/network/if-up.d/fstab

[2] Add this to it:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -a
```

[3] Make the file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/fstab
```

Anything placed in if-up.d will be executed only after the network it up and operational. THe "mount -a" directive will mount anything in fstab that isn't already mounted. So the next time you boot your shares should be mounted.

Comment: Seems you found the culprit!!!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `sec=ntlm`, at some point this option became invalid. I don't have a 16.04 system any more to check but I'm pretty sure that's your problem.